# Getting an error with constructor(error: '(' or '[' expected)

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, arguments, syntax-error

Im getting the error in the 1 arg constructor, for some reason its giving me the (error: '(' or '[' expected) error. When im pretty sure my brackets are all good and if there is issues I have no idea what they are. Please if anyone could help me i would greatly appreciate it. (Im a first year programmer so please go easy on me:))

````
public class Order{
//fields
double salesTaxRate;
double price;
double shippingCost;
double total;
double salesTax;
String array= new String
//1 arg constructor
public Order(double set1){
salesTaxRate=set1;
price=0;
shippingCost=0;
total=0;
salesTax=0;
}
//setPrice method
public void  setPrice(double p){
price=p;
salesTax=salesTaxRate*price;
double subTotal=(price+salesTaxRate);
if(subTotal<50){
shippingCost=0.8*subTotal;
}

else{
shippingCost=0;
}
}
//getTotalCost method
public double getTotalCost(){
   return total;
}
}
```
````

Comment: I think you forgot to place brackets after `new String`. It is a constructor, so it should be called. `new String()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String array= "";
```

or even

```
String array;
```

instead of <strike>`String array= new String`</strike>

Comment: 100% right i removed the array and it worked, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually on the row above the constuctor:

```java
String array= new String
//1 arg constructor
public Order(double set1){
```

You are missing the brackets for your `new String`. Instead it should be

```java
String array= new String();
//1 arg constructor
public Order(double set1){
```

Comment: Yeah it was the array, I saw that removed it and it compiled it, I appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 0):

What does `String array= new String` supposed to do?
if it supposed to declare a `String` variable with a name array then
change the `String array= new String` to `String array`.
If it's supposed to create an array of `String` then change it to `String[] array`

Comment: Thanks your your help yeah the array was in the wrong class it was suppouse to go in another one that i was writing and I never finished it.